# importing files from grass mapset to QGIS Layer Panel

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, layers

I am performing an NDVI calculation against 2 sets of rasters. One produced by LANDSAT5 the other by LANDSAT8.

```
r.mapcalc "L8_NDVI = float(L8Band5 - L8Band4) / (L8Band5 + L8Band4)"
```

The L8_NDVI file gets created successfully in my GRASS mapset.  I see it in all of the subdirectories (cell, cellhd, hist,etc.), but It does not appear in the QGIS Layers Panel. Is there a GRASS "Show Output On Map" command that I need to execute as follwoup to my ndvi command?

I tried the simple r.in.gdal command to import the layer form the mapset to the QGIS map, but it prompts me to overwrite the output file which also happens to be the input file.

Answer (score 1):

GRASS GIS is not QGIS. For importing the files from a GRASS mapset look at the [QGIS GRASS Cookbook](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/QGIS_GRASS_Cookbook). You can use

- The GRASS (6 or 7 version) plugin
- if GDAL/OGR is  properly configured in QGIS, you can directly open  the /.../cellhd/name_of_raster for rasters and the /.../vector/name_of_layer/head' file for vectors

#### New

Ok, therefore simply use the Browser Panel and move the layers to the QGIS canvas ([The QGIS GRASS plugin is back](https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2015/10/18/the-qgis-grass-plugin-is-back/))

[image]

But for GRASS 7.x, look at

Comment: Let me clarify a  bit, I am using QGIS Desktop 2.14.3 with Grass 7.0.4.  The Grass Plugin is active and installed.  I am using the Grass Tools within QGIS.

Comment: The layer files already exist in the mapset.  All I want to do is show them in the map (add them to the Layer Panel in QGIS).  I don’t want to recreate them in the mapset.  This is a similar process right clicking on a layer in the QGIS and selecting the ‘Remove Layer’ function.  The layer disappears from the layers panel on the QGIS map but it still exists in the mapset.  Is there way to restore that layer to the QGIS map?

Comment: look in new, above

Answer (score -2):

Navigate to where your GRASS mapset is in the Browser Panel and simply drag and drop from there.

Comment: Isn't that just part of what another answerer wrote and illustrated two years ago?